How do I track Vimeo URL source from Blackboard Learn?
I work in analytics for an online school that uses Blackboard Learn (SPA built with React). We are also using Vimeo to store our videos and to embed them to Blackboard with an iframe. So far, so good.
The thing is there's some videos that appear in more than one course, and I'm interested in segmenting the incoming traffic to see the differences based on location (a video might be performing very well in one space, but not so much somewhere else, etc.). Unfortunately, Vimeo only gives me one (1) URL for ALL traffic coming from Blackboard. That URL is the alternate domain of the Blackboard environment, which is used to load everything that comes via HTML (such as embeds). Vimeo videos are embedded in HTML blocks within the courses, and these blocks are served from the alternative domain instead of being served from the main URL.
Knowing this, is there a workaround here? Blackboad is not that popular and I'm struggling to find anything useful in the documentation. I've contacted with the company that is serving Blackboard to us, and they've tried to sell us an LTI integration that we can't integrate at the moment for other reasons.
Thanks.
